# JQuery, wrap div around every single div

Tags: jquery, wrapall

I´ve got a small script, that should wrap a div "wrap_mod_article" around every single parent div "mod_article".

```
if ($("body").hasClass("test")) {
    $('#content .mod_article').wrapAll('<div class="wrap_mod_article" />');
}
```

Right now the script creates one div thats around all divs with the class "mod_article".
How is it right to wrap a div "wrap_mod_article" around every div with "mod_article"?

http://jsfiddle.net/1t2a2nr4/2/

Comment: use `wrap()` instead of `wrapAll()` see docs [wrap jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Comment: Thank you on last question where is the best position to put this script, in the document.ready function or somewhere else?

Comment: if you want to wait untill the entire dom is loaded you could place it in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: Im sorry but I was wrong with my thinking. Is it possible to create a wrap div, inside every div with the class "mod_article". So that the content is inside the "mod_article" div gets wraped with the div "wrap_mod_article"?

Comment: Can you show us the html output that you want?

Comment: I used wrapInner: http://jsfiddle.net/1t2a2nr4/3/
But now I need i clear div on the bottom of the div "wrap_mod_article" how can I do that?´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a clear div at the bottom inside the `wrap_mod_article` use:

```
$('#content .mod_article .wrap_mod_article').append('<div class="clear" />');
```

The selector takes all `.wrap_mod_article` inside the `.mod_article` articles from the `content` container and appends the div with a class `clear`.

**Update jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/1t2a2nr4/4/